# numpy - return first index of element in array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

What's the fastest way of returning the index of the FIRST match between a variable and an element within an ndarray? I see numpy.where used a lot, but that returns all indices.

```
match = 5000
zArray = np.array([[0,1200,200],[1320,24,5000],[5000,234,5230]])

>array([[   0, 1200,  200],
   [1320,   24, 5000],
   [5000,  234, 5230]])

numpy.where(zArray==match)
>(array([1, 2], dtype=int64), array([2, 0], dtype=int64))
```

I'd like the first index returned, i.e. just [1,2]. but numpy.where returns both [1,2] and [2,0]

Comment: How would you define the *first* match ? Row major or column major ?

Comment: thanks guys, I need to clarify this a bit..

Comment: Be aware that your example array happens to be set such, that the two arrays in the result appear to be the two x, y index pairs you're looking for. Instead, these are the [x1, x2] and [y1, y2] indices of the matches. Try e.g. `[[0,5000,200],[1320,24,1200],[234,5000,5230]]` instead to see.

Comment: Just to iterate on what @Evert has mentioned, `"I'd like the first index returned, i.e. just [1,2]. but numpy.where returns both [1,2] and [2,0]"` needs edits I believe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`np.argwhere`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html) to get the matching indices packed as a 2D array with each row holding indices for each match and then index into the first row, like so -

```
np.argwhere(zArray==match)[0]
```

Alternatively, faster one with [`argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) to get the index of the first match on a flattened version and `np.unravel_index` for per-dim indices tuple -

```
np.unravel_index((zArray==match).argmax(), zArray.shape)
```

Sample run -

```
In [100]: zArray
Out[100]: 
array([[   0, 1200, 5000], # different from sample for a generic one
       [1320,   24, 5000],
       [5000,  234, 5230]])

In [101]: match
Out[101]: 5000

In [102]: np.argwhere(zArray==match)[0]
Out[102]: array([0, 2])

In [103]: np.unravel_index((zArray==match).argmax(), zArray.shape)
Out[103]: (0, 2)
```

Runtime test -

```
In [104]: a = np.random.randint(0,100,(1000,1000))

In [105]: %timeit np.argwhere(a==50)[0]
100 loops, best of 3: 2.41 ms per loop

In [106]: %timeit np.unravel_index((a==50).argmax(), a.shape)
1000 loops, best of 3: 493 µs per loop
```

Comment: `argwhere` is just `transpose(where(...))`.  It's handy for getting the first occurrence, but doesn't do any sort of short-circuiting.  `argmax` might short circuit the boolean match (I known the `nan` test does).

Comment: thanks Divakar. This works well, and is perfect for my needs.